# Is it possible to merge weak symbols like vtables/typeinfo across RTLD_LOCAL'ly loaded libraries?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, rtti, dlopen

For context: I have a Java project that is partially implemented with two JNI libraries.  For the sake of example, `libbar.so` depends on `libfoo.so`.  If these were system libraries,

```
System.loadLibrary("bar");
```

would do the trick.  But since they're custom libraries I'm shipping with my JAR, I have to do something like

```
System.load("/path/to/libfoo.so");
System.load("/path/to/libbar.so");
```

libfoo needs to go first because otherwise `libbar` can't find it, as it's not in the system library search path.

This has been working well for a while, but I've now run into an issue where `std::any_cast` is throwing `std::bad_any_cast` despite the types being correct.  I tracked it down to the fact that both libraries have a different definition of the typeinfo for that type, and they're not being merged at runtime.  This seems to be because `System.load()` ends up invoking `dlopen()` with `RTLD_LOCAL` rather than `RTLD_GLOBAL`.

I wrote this to demonstrate the behaviour without needing JNI:

> foo.hpp
>
> ```
> class foo { };
>
> extern "C" const void* libfoo_foo_typeinfo();
> ```
>
> foo.cpp
>
> ```
> #include "foo.hpp"
> #include <typeinfo>
>
> extern "C" const void* libfoo_foo_typeinfo()
> {
>     return &typeid(foo);
> }
> ```
>
> bar.cpp
>
> ```
> #include "foo.hpp"
> #include <typeinfo>
>
> extern "C" const void* libbar_foo_typeinfo()
> {
>     return &typeid(foo);
> }
> ```
>
> main.cpp
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <typeinfo>
> #include <dlfcn.h>
>
> int main() {
>     void* libfoo = dlopen("./libfoo.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);
>     void* libbar = dlopen("./libbar.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);
>
>     auto libfoo_fn = reinterpret_cast<const void* (*)()>(
>         dlsym(libfoo, "libfoo_foo_typeinfo"));
>     auto libbar_fn = reinterpret_cast<const void* (*)()>(
>         dlsym(libbar, "libbar_foo_typeinfo"));
>
>     auto libfoo_ti = static_cast<const std::type_info*>(libfoo_fn());
>     auto libbar_ti = static_cast<const std::type_info*>(libbar_fn());
>
>     std::cout << std::boolalpha
>               << (libfoo_ti == libbar_ti) << "\n"
>               << (*libfoo_ti == *libbar_ti) << "\n";
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Makefile
>
> ```
> all: libfoo.so libbar.so main
>
> libfoo.so: foo.cpp
>         $(CXX) -fpic -shared -Wl,-soname=$@ $^ -o $@
>
> libbar.so: bar.cpp
>         $(CXX) -fpic -shared -Wl,-soname=$@ $^ -L. -lfoo -o $@
>
> main: main.cpp
>         $(CXX) $^ -ldl -o $@
> ```

On my system, I get

```
$ make
...
$ ./main
false
true
```

This is because even though the typeinfo addresses are different, GCC's libstdc++ uses the mangled names for equality.  On LLVM's libc++, for example, equality is based on the typeinfo address itself, so I get:

```
$ make CXX="clang++ -stdlib=libc++"
$ ./main
false
false
```

If I pass `RTLD_GLOBAL` instead, I see

```
true
true
```

And if I edit `main.cpp` to load `libbar.so` first, it also works, provided I tell it where it can find `libfoo.so`:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
true
true
```

But for the reasons described at the top of this post, neither of these is a practical workaround.

This is very similar to https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/533 but with non-dynamic types, so there's no way to add a "key function" to force the typeinfo to be a strong symbol.  I happened to reproduce the problem on Android first, but it isn't Android-specific.

Comment: Nicely put question. Unfortunately I don't have an answer. But have an upvote for question quality.

Comment: You shouldn't use C++ for writing shared libraries: C++ is known for not working well together with dynamic loading.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I think that advice is a little pessimistic.  True there are more difficulties with dynamic libraries written in C++ but there are also many successful projects like Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. `RTLD_LOCAL` seeks to prevent exactly that, and unfortunately must be used for `System.loadLibrary` since otherwise bad things will happen if you `System.loadLibrary` two libraries that each define different `foo` classes.

Comment: Despite the `RTLD_LOCAL`, `libbar.so` is able to reference symbols from `libfoo.so`.  For example, everything works if you change `libbar_foo_typeinfo()` to `return libfoo_foo_typeinfo();`.  It seems strange that despite this, the vague linkage typeinfo symbols are unable to be merged.